# Grails - get request body from post request

Tags: grails, request, httprequest, grails-orm

I am fetching some problems with accessing post request body.

I try to read request body from request, but failed with the following errors:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: getInputStream() has already been called for this request`

And in my `UrlMappings`, `parseRequest` is set to `false`.

Comment: what happens if you " println request "

Comment: That is ok, valid request, no doubt.

Comment: This is because you are trying to read the request twice. Even before you read the request grails must have read it once. So it pops this error. You can try enabling multi read and keep the response in the memory and read it whenever required.